# Нужна помощь с логической функцией

Tags: python

Функция, которая принимает логическое значение, и если оно положительное, то возвращает лямбда-функцию, которая в свою очередь получает один аргумент (число), и возвращает его абсолютную величину (оно будет всегда положительным). Если число отрицательное, возвращается лямбда функция, получающая один аргумент (число), и всегда возвращает его с минусом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def func(b):
    if b:
        return lambda y: abs(y)
    return lambda y: -abs(y)


print(func(False)(1)) # -1
print(func(True)(-4)) # 4
```

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к правильному ответу, можно использовать **тернарный оператор**, чтобы уменьшить кол-во кода:

```py
def func(b):
    return (lambda y: abs(y)) if b else (lambda y: -abs(y))

print(func(False)(1)) # -1
print(func(True)(-4)) # 4
```

Впрочем, сработает даже и вот так, ещё короче:

```py
def func(b):
    return lambda y: (abs(y) if b else -abs(y))

print(func(False)(1)) # -1
print(func(True)(-4)) # 4
```

Или даже такой выверт:

```py
def func(b):
    return lambda y: (1,-1)[b] * abs(y)

print(func(False)(1)) # -1
print(func(True)(-4)) # 4
```